# How to install TP-Link TL-WN723N on Kali Linux(VMWARE)?

Tags: kali-linux, wifi-driver

I downloaded the driver from TP-Link website but I don't understand their guide it is included with the driver can anyone help me out ?

Here is the driver link: http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN723N_V3_150909.zip

Comment: What have you tried, and where do you get stuck, exactly? The guide provided in the archive is very detailed and pretty clear, albeit with some minor typos and whatnot. If you're asking others to rewrite the entire guide here, you are probably not getting anything.

Comment: @Larssend No mate I'm not asking for that but this is the first time I use Linux and I am confused what to edit in the make file I tried
cd ~/Desktop/Linux-Driver (where my driver is)
sudo make
it gives an error